# How can I install an app in a tvOS simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, tvos

I'm building an application for tvOS and would like our QA department to be able to do sanity/smoke tests without necessarily having an Apple TV device.  The people in the department can easily get access to Macs with Xcode.

I can build and package both device and simulator targets through our build system.

What I can't figure out (without a lot of hacking of UUID-named directories) is how to take a simulator build to a different machine and install it on a simulator there.

I'm interested in either a mechanism I've missed or scripting tips for how to install the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the `.app` bundle from the build directory under `Build/Products/debug-iphonesimulator`. Then drag & drop it on the Simulator window, or use `xcrun simctl install` to do it from a script or Terminal.

Comment: Drag and drop...never would have thought of that.  :)  Thanks!